# Filtering issue with multiple forloop in apex | salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have a scenario where multiple loopings are causing the system resource error.

I need some help with map of map syntax or coding sample for this requirement.

Requirement is:

- Account has 1 or more ReportCard records.
- ReportCard has Account and Contact.
- Now i need to get the list of ReportCards and filter by 1 per contact and recently created records only.
- If ReportCard has 2 records with same contact, include only recently created.

```
// get list of unique accounts from the set 
list<Account> accList = new list<Account >([SELECT Id,Average_of_Pulse_Check_Recommend_Score_N__c,Average_of_Recommend_Score_Lanyon_N__c,Average_of_Touchpoint_Recommend_Score_N__c,Average_of_Touch_Point_Satisfaction_N__c FROM Account WHERE Id in:AccIds]);

list<ReportCard__c> allRCList = new list<ReportCard__c>([SELECT Id,Net_Promoter_text__c,CreatedDate, Contact__c, Account__c, RecordTypeID, Touchpoint_Satisfaction_text__c FROM ReportCard__c WHERE Account__c in:accList Order By Account__c, CreatedDate Desc]);

List<ReportCard__c> rcListbyAccounts = new List<ReportCard__c>();

for(Account acc:accList)
{
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your situation correctly. You've skipped the for loop - I strongly suspect any issues you have there sit in the loop rather than in the queries.

Looks like you should read about using relationship queries (salesforce versions of JOIN in regular database): http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm
Pay special attention to subqueries (which behave similar to how a related list behaves on record's detail page).

---

From what I see I'd say you don't need to query for Accounts at all, or at least not like that. This will work equally well:

```
SELECT Id,Net_Promoter_text__c,CreatedDate, Contact__c, Account__c, ...
FROM ReportCard__c
WHERE Account__c in:accIds
ORDER BY Account__c, CreatedDate Desc
```

Now lets attack this:

> List of ReportCards and filter by 1 per contact and recently created
>   records only. If ReportCard has 2 records with same contact, include
>   only recently created.

I'd reverse it - I'd start the query from Contact level, go down to the related list of Report Cards and pick the latest one. That way it eliminates the issue with duplicate contacts for you. Something like this:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Email,
    (SELECT Id, Net_Promoter_text__c, CreatedDate, Account__c, Account__r.Name, Account__r.Average_of_Pulse_Check_Recommend_Score_N__c
    FROM ReportCards__r
    WHERE Account__c IN :accIds
    ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
    LIMIT 1)
FROM Contact
WHERE AccountId IN :accIds
```

This goes from Contact "down" to Report Cards (via the relationship name `ReportCards__r`) and then "up" from Card to Account via `Account__r.Name`, `Account__r.Average_of_Pulse_Check_Recommend_Score_N__c`...